# How to add item from visible/invisible dropdown list to flextable properly?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am having issues when I add items from the "blocksSizeList" and "briquettesSizeList" to the flextable.  For example, it will ignore the "blocksSizeList" and only add items from the "briquettesSizeList" even when hidden.  How can this be fixed?

```
function doGet(e) {
      var app = UiApp.createApplication();

     //Create horizontal product + other panel
      var productOtherPanel = app.createHorizontalPanel().setId('productOtherPanel')
      .setStyleAttribute('position','relative').setStyleAttribute('left','0%');

      //Create horizontal Product Panel  
      var productPanel = app.createHorizontalPanel().setId('productPanel').setStyleAttribute('position','relative')
      .setStyleAttribute('left','0%').setVisible(true);
      //Create listBox
      var productList = app.createListBox().setName("productList").setId('productList');
      //Add items to listBox
      productList.addItem("8:1 Compressed Blocks");
      productList.addItem("8:1 Compressed Briquettes");

      var handlerC = app.createServerHandler("panelHandler");
      productList.addChangeHandler(handlerC);

      //Create horizontal Compressed Blocks panel
      var blocksPanel = app.createHorizontalPanel().setId('blocksPanel')
      .setStyleAttribute('position','relative').setStyleAttribute('left','0%').setVisible(true);
      //Create Compressed Blocks Size List
      var blocksSizeList = app.createListBox().setName('blocksSizeList').setId('blocksSizeList');
      //addItem fills the Compressed Blocks Size List
      blocksSizeList.addItem("5kg");
      blocksSizeList.addItem("20kg");

      //Create horizontal Briquettes panel
      var briquettesPanel = app.createHorizontalPanel().setId('briquettesPanel')
      .setStyleAttribute('position','relative').setStyleAttribute('left','0%').setVisible(false);
      //Create Briquettes Size List
      var briquettesSizeList = app.createListBox().setName('briquettesSizeList').setId('briquettesSizeList');
      //addItem fills the Briquettes Size List
      briquettesSizeList.addItem("250g");
      briquettesSizeList.addItem("650g");

      //Create hidden app      
      var hidden = app.createHidden().setName('hidden').setId('hidden').setValue('1')
      //Create button handler
      var handlerB = app.createServerHandler("buttonHandler");
      // pass the listbox into the handler function as a parameter and the hidden widget as well
      handlerB.addCallbackElement(productList).addCallbackElement(hidden);
      handlerB.addCallbackElement(blocksSizeList).addCallbackElement(hidden);
      handlerB.addCallbackElement(briquettesSizeList).addCallbackElement(hidden);

      //Create flextable 
      var quotesFlexTable = app.createFlexTable().setId("quotesFlexTable")
      .setStyleAttribute('position','relative').setStyleAttribute('left','0%');

      //Create flex table style attributes
        quotesFlexTable.setStyleAttribute("border-style", "solid");
        quotesFlexTable.setStyleAttribute("border-width", "1px");  
        quotesFlexTable.setCellPadding(5);



      //Create flex table headers  
      quotesFlexTable.setWidget(0, 0, app.createLabel("Product Type")).setStyleAttribute("color", "blue");
      quotesFlexTable.setWidget(0, 1, app.createLabel("Size")); 

      var button = app.createButton("+", handlerB);

      // add all widgets to the app

      //Add all widgets to the app




      app.add(quotesFlexTable).add(hidden);
      app.add(productOtherPanel);
      productOtherPanel.add(productPanel);
      productPanel.add(productList);
      productOtherPanel.add(blocksPanel);
      blocksPanel.add(blocksSizeList);
      productOtherPanel.add(briquettesPanel);
      briquettesPanel.add(briquettesSizeList);
      productOtherPanel.add(button);


      return app;
    }

    function buttonHandler(e) {
      var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
      // get the position (is a string)
      var pos = e.parameter.hidden;
      // initial condition, hidden widget is empty
      // convert to number
       pos=Number(pos);
      var quotesFlexTable = app.getElementById("quotesFlexTable");
      // add the new item at the right place
      quotesFlexTable.insertRow(pos).insertCell(pos, 0).setText(pos, 0, e.parameter.productList)
      .setText(pos, 1, e.parameter.blocksSizeList).setText(pos, 1, e.parameter.briquettesSizeList);
      // increment position
      ++pos;
      // save value
      app.getElementById('hidden').setValue(pos);
      // update app
      return app;
      }

    function panelHandler(event) {
      var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
      if (event.parameter.productList == "8:1 Compressed Blocks") {
        app.getElementById('blocksPanel').setVisible(true);
        app.getElementById('briquettesPanel').setVisible(false);
      }
      else if (event.parameter.productList == "8:1 Compressed Briquettes") {
        app.getElementById('blocksPanel').setVisible(false);
        app.getElementById('briquettesPanel').setVisible(true);
      }
      return app;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the flex table cell twice in your buttonHandler function. The second time always overwrites the first time so you're only seeing the briquettes size added. Change it to the following:

```
if (e.parameter.productList == "8:1 Compressed Blocks") {
  quotesFlexTable.insertRow(pos).insertCell(pos, 0).setText(pos, 0, e.parameter.productList).setText(pos, 1, e.parameter.blocksSizeList);
    }
else {
  quotesFlexTable.insertRow(pos).insertCell(pos, 0).setText(pos, 0, e.parameter.productList).setText(pos, 1, e.parameter.briquettesSizeList);
}
```